# Google Play Console: How do I update the APK files of a Closed Test?

Tags: google-play-console, release-management, google-people-api

I accidentally uploaded erroneous APK-files for a Closed Test of my app, on the Google Play Console. How can I update the APK files - in other word - replace them with the new correct version?

I find the Google Play Console quite confusing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply create a new apk file with a higher version-code,
and publish it to the same closed test group on Google Play Console.